# How do you find the range of a given function? Is there a process to follow?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have never quite understood how to evaluate domains and ranges of functions. I specifically have trouble with ranges.

For simple ones, like quadratic equations, I can usually find the minimum point and give a correct answer.

But take, for example:
$$ f(x) = \frac{3}{2x+1}, x > 0$$
and
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x} + 2, x > 0$$

I am so confused with the whole process of finding the ranges of functions, including those above as samples, that I can't even quite explain what or why.

Can someone please, in a very step-by-step process, detail exactly what steps you would take to get the ranges of the above functions? I tried substituting x-values (such as 0), and came up with $f(x) > 3$, but that was mostly guesswork -- also, $f(x) > 3$ is incorrect.

Also, is there an outline I can follow -- even for the thinking process, like check if A, check if B -- that would work every time?

Comment: Are you familiar with limits?

Comment: They've given me the concept of limits -- getting closer and closer to something but never quite getting there -- but haven't gotten too deep into it yet.

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tough to come up with a *univeral* checklist, but I will
take a stab at it.

The first question is, is the function [e.g. $f(x)$]
**well defined** for each value in the domain.  For example:

With respect to $f(x)$, if the constraint had allowed $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ 
then you would have a problem.  Since the domain is restricted 
to $x > 0$, for any **finite** value of $x$, the function is well defined.

With respect to $g(x)$, you have a virtually identical consideration. 
Since the domain does **not** allow $x=0, g(x)$ is well defined throughout
its domain.

The next question is whether, in your opinion, the function is **continuous**.

The reason that this is important, is that if you are examining (for example) 
some function $h(x)$, and you know that $h(x)$ is continuous, and you also 
know that you can identify two points $x_1, x_2$ in the domain of $h(x)$, 
**then** you know that the **range must contain** every value between
$h(x_1)$ and $h(x_2).$

The next step is to identify the endpoints of the domain, and consider
whether each endpoint **is or is not** in the domain.

With both of your functions, the lower endpoint is $0$, and the endpoint
is not in the domain.  Similarly, the upper endpoint of both functions
is $\infty$, which is not a number, but rather a symbol that the upper
end of the domain is unbounded.

The way that I would handle the endpoints, is to **pretend** that you
have two positive real numbers $a,b$ with $a < b$, and you are first
considering the domain as all $x$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$.

Then, you consider the **actual** domain as the limit of the domain
determined in the previous paragraph, as $a \to 0$ and $b \to \infty$.

Since you are after a checklist, rather than the actual answers with
respect to the specific functions $f$ and $g$, that you provided, this
should be sufficient for you to solve this particular problem and also
work with similar problems in the future.

Please leave a comment directly below my answer, if you have any questions.
I will automatically be flagged.

---

**Addendum** 
Response to comments/questions of : A Level Student : re 10-10-2020

First of all, I'd like to excerpt a point that amwhy commented to Darsen's answer:

> Typically questions in algebra-precalculus to not presume knowledge of limits.

And my response:

> @amWhy +1 (also) on your comment, which I agree with. However, it is hard to
> fathom how the OP is supposed to systematically evaluate the range of values
> given the domain of $0 < x$, without consideration of limits, as per my answer.

What I mean by this, is it is hard for me to conjure a *systematic* method,
as per your request, without **assuming** (in this case **wrongly**) that you
have a working knowledge of limits.  What I will do, is **continue to assume**
that you understand limits, at least within the confines of my answer.

**However** I invite further questions.  Please continue to post them directly
after my answer.

What I am going to do is respond to the specific questions that you raised in
your comments **first**.  Then, I will pretend that I was assigned the problem
and describe how I would identify the range of $f(x)$ and the range of $g(x)$.

> 1. So I tried to apply the method. We established that f(x) is continuous
>    (and well-defined, because it gives no exceptions, right?). Then we established
>    that the lower endpoint of my DOMAIN is 0, not included, and the upper endpoint
>    is infinity. After that, we pick two numbers (a<b) within our defined domain.

For **this portion** of your first comment, I agree with everything so far, except that it is not
a good idea to think of the upper endpoint as equaling infinity.  This comes
too close to regarding infinity as a number, rather than a symbol.  You would
do better to say that the upper endpoint is **unbounded**.

> So I pick a=4 and b=8. f(4)=1/3, and f(8)=3/17. ...

Your confusion here is my fault for not providing clear details about what
to do with the idea that you first pretend that the domain is $a \leq x \leq b$,
and then examine what happens as $a \to 0$, and $b \to \infty.$

See the later portion of my addendum, where I provide better details about
specifically attacking the problem you posted in your query.

> ...... so that 0 is my next endpoint? So I write it out like this: ...

Again, see the later portion of my addendum.

> What's the difference between well-defined and continuous?

The best way to answer this question is to first examine this question with
respect to the sample functions in your original query.  Then, make more general
comments.  Your functions are:

$$ f(x) = \frac{3}{2x+1}, x > 0$$
and
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x} + 2, x > 0$$

Consider what would happen if you tried to examine $f(x)$ for **any** real number
$x$, rather than only those values of $x$ that are greater than $0$.  $f(x)$ has
$(2x+1)$ in its denominator, and division by $0$ is **forbidden**.  Therefore,
$f(x)$ is not well defined at $x = \frac{-1}{2}.$

Similarly, if you tried to examine $g(x)$ for **any** real number $x$, you would
find that $g(x)$ is not well defined at $x=0$.

So the concept of well defined means that a function [e.g. $f(x)$] is **not** well defined at
a specific value $x = x_0$ if you are unable to assign a specific (**finite**)
value to $f(x_0)$.

Continuity is an entirely different subject.  Understanding this subject **requires**
significant experience with limits.  The best that I can do at this point is to
give you an **intuitive, informal** idea of what *Continuity* is supposed to represent.

If you have a function with a specific domain (for example all $x$ such that $x > 0$),
and you are wondering whether the function is **continuous** throughout the domain,
simply ask yourself this:  when I go to manually graph the function, can I do so
**without picking up my pencil.**

With both of the functions that you provided, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the answer is
yes.  Therefore, you are able to assume that (for example), that if $x_1$ and $x_2$
are in the domain of $f(x)$, with $x_1 < x_2$, then the range of $f(x)$ **must include**
every value between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

Informally, this is because as you are graphing the function with your pencil,
as your pencil travels from $f(x_1)$ to $f(x_2)$, you are **not allowed** to
pick up your pencil.  Therefore the graph **must traverse** every point between
$f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

This begs the question: how in the world do you try to determine whether a specific
function is or is not continuous?  This is an enormously complicated question,
well beyond what I can address in my answer.  However, I can give you an intuitive
idea of what a **discontinuous** function might look like.

Consider the function $s(x)$ defined on the domain $0 < x < 3$ as follows:

$$\text{For} ~0 < x < 1, s(x) = 0.$$

$$\text{For} ~1 \leq x < 2, s(x) = 1.$$

$$\text{For} ~2 \leq x < 3, s(x) = 2.$$

A reasonable way of thinking about this function $s(x)$ is that you can **not**
graph the function **without** picking up your pencil.  Therefore $s(x)$ is
**not** continuous throughout its domain of $0 < x < 3$.

> Also, if my function is not well-defined, or continuous ...
> I can't use the above method? But I can still find the range?

Yes absolutely.  But providing a **systematic** way of doing so, in these
more complicated situations is well beyond what I can cover in this answer.

So for the purposes of this answer, it is important to

- Verify that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are each well defined in the domain of $0 < x$,
  which they are.
- Presume, that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, because (very informally) it
  **seems** that you can graph each of these functions without picking up your pencil.
- After accepting the presumption of continuity, realizing that as a consequence,
  that (for example) if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both in the range of $f(x)$, with $x_1 < x_2$, then the range of $f(x)$ must include
  all values **between** $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

$\underline{\text{attacking the problem you posted in your query}}$

I will attack them one at a time.

$$ f(x) = \frac{3}{2x+1}, x > 0$$

Start with the **pretense** that the domain of $x$ is $a \leq x \leq b$, 
with $a < b$, where **for the moment**, $a$ and $b$ are going to be regarded
as **unspecified values** (i.e. **variables**).

Then,

$$ f(a) = \frac{3}{2a+1} ~\text{and} ~f(b) = \frac{3}{2b+1}$$

Furthermore, with $f(x) = \frac{3}{2x+1}$, ask yourself:

As $x$ increases, is $f(x)$ strictly decreasing?

Answer:
**Yes**, because as $x$ increases, the **denominator** will increase, which
causes the value of $f(x)$ to decrease.

Therefore, the **maximum** value for $f(x)$ will be achieved as $x$ is allowed
to decrease as much as possible.

As $a$ **approaches** $0$ from above, $f(x)$ will **aproach**

$$f(x) = \frac{3}{2[0]+1} = \frac{3}{1} = 3.$$

Similarly, as $b$ increases in an unbounded manner 
$f(x)$ will be decreasing.  What is the smallest value that $f(x)$ can achieve?

As $b$ increases, the denominator will be able to take on any value.  Therefore,
the denominator of $f(x)$ will be **unbounded**.

If you have a fraction $\frac{P}{Q}$, where $P > 0$ is a fixed value, and $Q$ can
get **arbitrarily large**, then the fraction will *go to zero*.  That is, as $Q$
grows, any **small** positive value of $\frac{P}{Q}$ can be achieved.

Using this concept with respect to $f(x)$, we see that as $b$ grows unbounded,
$f(x)$ will **approach** $0$ from above.  This means that **any** small postive
value will fall within the range of $x$.

Therefore, in conclusion, for $f(x)$ the range of $f(x)$ is:

$$0 < f(x) < 3.$$

Notice that I used the phrase "$b$ grows unbounded", rather than the terminology
$b \to \infty$.  Although the terminology is appropriate, I deliberately avoided
using it simply to **emphasize** the idea that infinity is a **symbol** rather than
a number.  Infinity symbolizes unbounded growth.

At this point, you have a valid claim of **Foul**.

You asked for a systematic method.  The approach that I used, after pretending
that the domain was $a \leq x \leq b$ and examining what happens when
$a \to 0$ and $b \to \infty$ was **anything but systematic**.

I regard this as a very valid complaint.  Unfortunately, given the problems
that you will be assigned in the future, I am unable to provide a rigorous
checklist of the steps that you take.  These steps will depend on the problems
that you are assigned.

The best that I can do is provide the worked examples for the specific $f(x)$
and $g(x)$ that you gave.  The idea is for you to use these worked examples
as a guide; this is the best that I can do.

To finish, I will similarly attack $g(x)$ :

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x} + 2, x > 0$$

I am going to use virtually the same ideas that I used when attacking $f(x)$.

If the domain were $a \leq x \leq b$ then,

$$g(a) = \frac{1}{a} + 2 ~\text{and} ~g(b) = \frac{1}{b} + 2.$$

Again, in $g(x)$, $x$ is occuring in the denominator only, so 
as $x$ increases, $g(x)$ decreases and as $x$ decreases, $g(x)$ increases.

As $a \to 0, ~\frac{1}{a}$ will $\to \infty$ (i.e. grow unbounded).  Therefore,
the upper end of the range of $g(x)$ is **unbounded**.

As $b \to \infty, \frac{1}{b}$ will go to $0$. 
Therefore, as $b \to \infty,$ $g(b)$ will go to $0 + 2$. 
It is critical to note that for any **finite** value of $b, g(b) > 2.$

Therefore, the range of $g(x)$ is

$$ 2 < g(x).  ~\text{Notice that} ~2 ~\text{is not part of the range.}$$

Comment: 1. So I tried to apply the method. We established that f(x) is continuous (and well-defined, because it gives no exceptions, right?). Then we established that the lower endpoint of my DOMAIN is 0, not included, and the upper endpoint is infinity. After that, we pick two numbers ($a < b$) within our defined domain. So I pick $ a = 4$ and $b = 8$. $f(4) = 1/3$, and $f(8) = 3/17$. Next, as $4$ gets closer and closer to 0, I find that $f(x)$ seems to get closer and closer to 3. So that's one endpoint of the range? And as $8$ gets closer and closer to infinity, $f(x)$ seems to get closer to 0...

Comment: ... so that $0$ is my next endpoint? So I write it out like this: $0 < f(x) < 3$. Employing the same process to $g(x)$, I think I get $2< g(x) < infinity$

Comment: 2. What's the difference between well-defined and continuous? Also, if my function is not well-defined, or continuous (i.e. if it were $x > -5, x \neq 0$), I can't use the above method? But I can still find the range?

Comment: @ALevelStudent Please see my answer's addendum, which addresses all three of your comments.

Answer (score 2):

I added an additional explanation for the limits part at the end.

For $f$ you have that $x>0\Rightarrow 2x>0\Rightarrow2x+1>1\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{2x+1}<1\Rightarrow\dfrac{3}{2x+1}<3$. On the other hand, $2x+1>1>0\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{2x+1}>0\Rightarrow\dfrac{3}{2x+1}>0$. So $0<f(x)<3$ for every $x>0$. Furthermore, $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=3$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$, so, since $f$ is continuous in $(0,+\infty)$, we have that the range of $f$ is all of $(0,3)$.

For $g$ is similar. We have that for $x>0\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{x}>0\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{x}+2>2$. So $g(x)>2$ for every $x>0$. Furthermore, $\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=2$, so, since $g$ is continuous in $(0,+\infty)$, we have that the range of $g$ is all of $(2,+\infty)$.

---

I've been told that maybe I shouldn't use limits to justify the ranges, so I'll explain a little bit what I would say with words in the last part of the first paragraph if I didn't use limits.

For $f(x)=\dfrac{3}{2x+1}$ we have that $0<f(x)<3$ for every $x>0$. Now, we can see that, as $x$ goes closer and closer to $0$ then the $2x$ part of the denominator starts to get smaller and smaller, almost vanishing. If we could take $x=0$ then we would get $3$ as a value, but since we can't we can just say that the values of $f$ keep getting closer and closer to $3$; thus the parenthesis for the $3$ in the range.

If we make $x$ go bigger and bigger then $2x+1$ gets bigger and bigger, making the fraction $\dfrac{3}{2x+1}$ go smaller and smaller, almost vanishing into $0$. It never actually becomes $0$, but it keeps getting closer from above (from the positive numbers); thus the parenthesis for $0$ in the range. $f$ is a good function in $(0,+\infty)$: there are no "explosions" in the denominator, and it's defined always by the same expression.

This is not sufficient to say that $f$ is continuous, but it does look good. If you have the tools or the information so you can assert $f$ is indeed continuous, use it, since then $f$ can't jump from one value to another one, it has to go *continuously* from one to the other, taking all values in between. This is the same as thinking that if you want to get to a certain height from the ground, you'll have to be at some moment at ever height in between. Then $f$ takes every value between $0$ and $3$, since it can be as close to those values as we want.

Now you can try this reasoning with $g$.

Comment: Typically questions in algebra-precalculus to not presume knowledge of limits.

Comment: I think in the range of $g$ there‘s a small typo, maybe you mean $(2,+\infty)$?

Comment: Corrected; thanks!

Comment: @amWhy +1 (also) on your comment, which I agree with.  However, it is hard to fathom how the OP is supposed to *systematically* evaluate the range of values given the domain of $0 < x$, without consideration of limits, as per my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using that logic. So $g(x)$ has a domain of $0 < x < infinity$. As I make $x$ get bigger, $g(x)$ seems to get closer to 2. As I make $x$ get smaller and smaller, and closer to $0$, $g(x)$ seems to become bigger and bigger (so tending to infinity). So I can say that $2 < g(x) < infinity$?

Comment: You can say that, but you need to add that $g$ is getting closer to $2$ from above, since $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is bigger than $0$ for every $x>0$. However, although $2<g(x)<\infty$ is true and you can say $(2,\infty)$ is the range, you can't say if that 's the image of $g$ just yet.

Comment: There's a difference between image and range: if you know $g$ takes values in a certain set of numbers $B$, then you can say that $B$ is a range of values of $g$, but this just means that every value of $g$ must be in $B$, not that for every number $b$ in $B$ there is some point $x$ such that $g(x)=b$.

Comment: In this case the inequality $2<g(x)<\infty$ tells us that every value of $g$ is in $(2,\infty)$, but we don't know if $g$ takes all values in $(2,\infty)$. But this is sufficient to call $(2,\infty)$ a range of $g$, so if that's the question, that's an answer. Another answer could be $(0,\infty)$ too, since every value of $g$ is there too, but it's a worse answer, because the first is more restrictive.

Comment: On the other hand, the image *is* the set Im($g$) of all values of $g$, meaning that every value of $g$ is there (as happened with the range), but also that every number in Im($g$) is a value that $g$ takes at some moment.

Comment: As I said, the inequality $2<g(x)<\infty$ can't tell us if every value in $(2,\infty)$ is attained, so we can't call it the image. To call it that, we need to use the continuity of $g$, so we can say $g$ is taking every value in the way as it gets closer to $2$, and the same as it grows and grows to infinity. To conclude I'll repeat that if they're asking you for the range, be reassured, $(2,\infty)$ is justified with the inequality,

Comment: Thank you, thank you... this is about as clear an understanding as anyone could have given me!

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about the example you gave: f(x) = 3/(2x + 1), with domain x > 0

To answer your first question, there are two "domains" of a function: (1) a given set of inputs to consider, and (2) every possible input that doesn't blow up in your face. In the case of this f(x), we say "for x > 0", and so this is the first case. We *could* plug in any value of x so long as 2x + 1 is not equal to zero.

Since we are strictly considering x > 0, we can manipulate this inequality to infer a similar inequality on f(x): namely, f(x) < 3. This is done by the manipulations:

1. x > 0,
2. 2x > 0,
3. 2x + 1 > 1
4. 1 > 1/(2x + 1) (careful with whether > or < here)
5. 3 > 3/(2x + 1),
   so 3 > f(x).

This is certainly true, but it isn't the entire story. If consider a point in our range y = f(x) for some x > 0, then what is the corresponding value for x? This is the inverse function. We can certainly solve for it:

1. 3/(2x + 1) = y
2. 3/y = 2x + 1
3. 3/y - 1 = 2x
4. x = 3/(2y) - 1/2.

For example, if I know that f(x) = 1, then the value of x must be 3/2 - 1/2 = 2/2 = 1. Now consider: what value of y am I not allowed to plug in? Since dividing by zero is not allowed, we cannot have y = 0, meaning that there is no x such that f(x) = 0.

Now, if y is not zero, then it must be either (1) y > 0 or (2) y < 0. However, if y < 0, then 3/(2x+1) < 0. Hence, 3/(2x+1) < 0, and multiplying by (2x + 1), we get a false statement: 3 < 0 (again, careful with whether > or < here) So (2) cannot be true, and (1) must be true: y > 0, that is, f(x) > 0.

Combining these results: 3 > f(x) > 0. This illustrates my process for finding the range of a function. First, can you make any inferences about where f(x) could be using your domain? I showed that if x > 0 then 3 > f(x). Second, if you can find it, use the inverse function to try and pin down where f(x) lives.